# LAMP / jquery Advanced searching

Tags: php, search, lamp

I'm redesigning a website with over 30K entries for users to browse through.  I've mocked up several different ideas, but I've been unhappy with the results each time.

I want to try a search similar to newegg/ebay, with left side search categories,breadcrumbs across the top, etc.  Unfortunately, I don't even know what to call that.  I've tried searching, but to no avail.

Since I'm mocking up ideas, I don't want to spend too much time implementing this so I was hoping that there was an extant framework out there I could use.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question's a bit broad but if you're open to switching to a whole new CMS, [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) ticks all of the boxes by default and if very flexible with menu block-placement. The [Ubercart](http://www.ubercart.org/) plugin would be worth looking into if it's an eCommerce site.